# Is it possible to do a post-hoc test on a factorial ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

Is it possible to do a post-hoc test on a factorial ANOVA?

I have three independent variables (sex, age and depth) and then a single dependent value (BV/TV).

This is the R script I've been using for the ANOVA -

```
anova(lm(BVTV ~ Sex * Age * Depth, data = SD_MFC_DATA))
```

Here is some example data:

[image: Example Male data]
[image: Example female data]

I'd like to see where my significant differences are occurring i.e., which slice numbers (and therefore depth) do sign. changes occur?

Is this possible?

**Edit**: I have additionally realised that my degrees are freedom are appearing as 1, which is clearly incorrect. When I change my IVs to factors, I can no longer do the factorial ANOVA, as I get this error message

```
Warning message:
In anova.lm(lm(BVTV ~ Sex * Age * Depth, data = SD_MFC_DATA)) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

Comment: Yes, you should look at the `emmeans`  package.

Comment: I've looked into the lsmeans and argicolae packages but haven't had much luck - I'll look into emmeans now, many thanks!

Comment: `emmeans` is similar to `lsmeans` .  `lemeans` would also have done what you want, but `lsmeans` is now deprecated.  ... My recommendation for using this site is to edit your question with a reproducible example and be specific as to what you want to know.  A reproducible example doesn't need real data, but it's something I can literally cut and paste into R without modification.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thanks Sal, I have added the example data. Unfortunately as there is so much data and I can't use table HTML on this forum, I've had to paste images. I hope it's still useful and provides some context. I've additionally had another error arise and have edited that into the post. Thanks in advance

Comment: In response to the Edit.  Yes, you probably want your IV's as factors.  (Though *Age* and *Depth* could be numeric, depending).  For the data set you show, it's correct that *Sex* and *Age* have 1 degree of freedom as factors.  Also for the data set you show, you don't have any replicated values within each *Sex x Age x Depth* combination, so the model testing can't work it's magic correctly.  A solution is to use fewer interactions, like `(BVTV ~ Sex + Age + Depth + Sex:Age + Sex:Depth + Age:Depth`.

Comment: Oh brilliant, I was worried that it was incorrect for age to have 1 d.f. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you Sal, I'll retry that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some pieces of an answer in the comments to the question, regarding the failure of hypothesis tests for the saturated model, and whether to handle some independent variables as factors.

The following sketches out a potential solution in R for a post-hoc approach for a factorial anova.  As an illustration, it uses different data for the `BVTV` variable.  It does not check model assumptions or ensure this kind of model is appropriate for the data, though these should be considered in a real situation.  It's also not clear that the model using the all two-way interactions would be the most appropriate.

```
set.seed(sum(utf8ToInt("MeanPeopleAreMean")))

Sex   = factor(rep(c("M", "F"), each = 20))
Age   = factor(rep(c("21", "41", "21", "41"), each = 10))
Depth = factor(rep(1:10, 4))
BVTV  = as.numeric(Sex)+as.numeric(Age)+as.numeric(Depth)/10 + 
        as.numeric(Sex)*as.numeric(Age)*3 +
        rnorm(length(Sex), 0, 1)

model = lm(BVTV ~ Sex + Age + Depth + Sex:Age + Sex:Depth + Age:Depth)

anova(model)

### Normally, I would use the Anova function in the car package,
###  but right now there's a mismatch in some package versions,
###  or something causing trouble for me.

   ### Response: BVTV
   ###          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
   ### Sex        1 321.79  321.79 377.0660 1.178e-08 ***
   ### Age        1 296.07  296.07 346.9281 1.699e-08 ***
   ### Depth      9  16.03    1.78   2.0875  0.144043    
   ### Sex:Age    1  12.81   12.81  15.0098  0.003764 ** 
   ### Sex:Depth  9  12.67    1.41   1.6493  0.233799    
   ### Age:Depth  9  10.47    1.16   1.3633  0.325892    
   ### Residuals  9   7.68    0.85                       

library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model, ~ Sex:Age)

pairs(marginal)

   ###  contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
   ###  F,21 - M,21   -4.541 0.413  9 -10.991 <.0001 
   ###  F,21 - F,41   -4.309 0.413  9 -10.431 <.0001 
   ###  F,21 - M,41  -11.114 0.413  9 -26.901 <.0001 
   ###  M,21 - F,41    0.231 0.413  9   0.560 0.9414 
   ###  M,21 - M,41   -6.573 0.413  9 -15.910 <.0001 
   ###  F,41 - M,41   -6.804 0.413  9 -16.470 <.0001 
   ###
   ### Results are averaged over the levels of: Depth 
   ### P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

Comment: Hi Sal, this was brilliant, it worked perfectly for me! Unfortunately, I have another issue now, I'd really appreciate your input (or anyone elses!) if possible. I am now using percentages for depth now, so I'm having an issue running the post-hoc tests. Are these still possible now I am working in percentages, as they are still interval?

Comment: It should be fine to use a percentage for depth, except it will enter the model as a numeric variable rather than a `factor` variable.  So, `depth` will have a df of 1, as will `sex:depth` and `age:depth`.  (Assuming this doesn't cause the new model to not meet model assumptions).

Comment: Thanks again Sal, that all makes sense. The post-hoc tests are fine when I do ``marginal = emmeans(model, ~ Sex:Age)``, however, when I go to compare ``Sex:Depth``, I get this `` contrast        estimate      SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0,21.4 - 1,21.4   0.0247 0.00382 326 6.459   <.0001 

Results are averaged over the levels of: Age `` , which is clearly not comparing the percentage depths with sex. Am I right in assuming that post-hoc tests with percentage is not possible now?

Comment: Well, if depth is being treated as numeric variable, it's not going to give you the comparisons for each level of depth... If that's what you want, you can treat depth as a factor variable and just have the labels as percents, e.g. `"15%"` or `"10 - 15%"`.

Comment: Thanks Sal, sorry for all these questions, I've been looking at this data for so long now it's hard to see the obvious answers! I've now grouped the percentage depths now so it's working. Fingers crossed that should be everything now!